# fatal error while bundle install (while installing libv8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I work on windows7 (32-bit) and I get error that while bundle install;

```
Installing libv8 (3.3.10.4) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

       C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
Checking for Python... Unable to build libv8: Python not found!
```

So I can't complete "bundle install".

Answer (score 6):

Install ActivePython version 2.7.2.5, then run:

```
gem install libv8 --version 3.11.8.0
```

to install the libv8 in Windows, the latest version 3.11.8.3 can not work in windows, but 3.11.8.0 can in Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

On windows 7, with ruby193 I installed python27, I added to the PATH variable the python's folder, I wrote gem install libv8 in the console and libv8 was succesfully installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to install python since libv8 seems to depend on Python as you can see [in project stats](https://github.com/fractaloop/libv8/graphs/languages)

Comment: but my project is written with ruby on rails. Do I need Python?

Comment: If one dependency of your project is written in another language, you will need support for it, in this case is Python. This usually is not an issue since Python is installed on most unix flavors.

Comment: Thank you Paulo I am trying now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I opened  [issue 29](https://github.com/fractaloop/libv8/issues/29)  on github and I learned that libv8 is not supported on windows. so there is no solution for the error. Just you can change your platform.