# bundle install libv8 (therubyracer) installation fails (with native extensions) on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to do a bundle install on my windows machine and I have tried to include the two following gems:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'libv8', '3.3.10.4'
```

But neither seem to work which leaves me with this error:

```
Installing libv8 (3.3.10.4) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bun
dler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: F
ailed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby
Checking for Python...Unable to build libv8: Python not found!


Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:511:in `block in build_extensions'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `build_extensions'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:159:in `install'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:90:in `block in install'

        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:82:in `pre
serve_paths'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:89:in `install'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:73:in `block in insta
ll_gem_from_spec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:97:in `wit
h_build_args'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:72:in `install_gem_fr
om_spec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:56:in `block in run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `
invoke_task'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'

        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Is there a way around this thank you

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174328/fatal-error-while-bundle-install-while-installing-libv8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the language dependencies: https://github.com/fractaloop/libv8/graphs/languages

You'll need to install Python on your machine. I'd also install the latest version of bundler once that's done:

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, tried following the github commands, and the git clone address hung up. I installed nodejs and did it that way. Which should be okay should it not?

Comment: Are you talking about Python or libv8? If it's working then it should be ok. Are you on a work network? Your firewall might be blocking the git address.

Comment: @Simpleton did you install therubyracer on Windows, successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Python 2.7 installed and in your Windows path.